# Rails not running with Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

To run Rails with Thin server I usually add `thin` gem to `Gemfile`, then I run `bundle install`, and then restart my development server.

But now it's not working, how can I debug this behaviour?

I mean this with not working:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

I am using `Zeus` gem, can this be related? I restarted `zeus` server.

Comment: right, thanks, will update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a problem with my Rails version, updated to `3.2.13` and now it works, maybe the problem was other, but that update fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use thin and zeus so maybe I can help. In your `Gemile` put thin in `:development`

```
group :development do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

It should be picked up automatically. However, sometimes I have to restart zeus all together. so stop zeus with `control-c`, after it quits, run `zeus start`, then when server is green on the zeus screen, run `zeus server`

Try that out in order and see if that works for you

Also make sure that zeus is not in your `Gemfile`. If you use `rvm` just install it in your `global gemset`. Bundler should not use zeus.

Comment: Changed `thin` to development, restarted zeus, restarted rails server, zeus not in my Gemfile, I use rbenv. Not working. I have two projects the other is working fine with thin. I Don't know where the problem could be.

Comment: I got pulled away form the computer but I was going to suggest passing in thin after zeus server. oh well, at least you got it running.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just saw the self answer, but I'm going to explain *why* it worked anyway.

Using thin as a rails server works in newer versions of Rails (3.2+)

However, looking at the output from `rails server` you're running Rails 3.1.3. I don't think using `thin` for `rails server` was implemented in that version.

In your version of Rails you'll probably need to call `thin` expicitly, instead of assuming `rails server` will figure it out.

My suggestion would be to use a Procfile (see [a good guide for development as well as deployment](http://www.neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend/) and set up your `web` process to run `thin` instead of `rails server). With foreman / a Procfile you don't have to worry about which server you need to use, or what other services you need to start up (redis, memcached, etc). Plus if you deploy to Heroku you need a Procfile anyway.